# Allow disabled objects via Extbase Route Enhancer in TYPO3

Tags: php, yaml, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have a controller for showing trainees by a certain given training.
So originaly there was *\vendor\extension\Domain\Model\Training $training* inside the parameter list of the *showTrainees()* function.

Now our customer (using the TYPO3 environment) wants us to enable showing *trainees* even when they disable a corresponding *training*. So I removed the parameter requirement and put it into the function itself by getting it from the parameter list and adding:

```
// set training repo to ignore hidden
$defaultQuerySettings = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings();
$defaultQuerySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields(true);
$defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
$this->trainingRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
```

So far so good. Now the problem is the Extbase Route Enhancer. Because it doesn't create the domain if the corresponding entity is not enabled. Is there a way to do that?

Here the current route config:

```
  Trainee:
    limitToPages:
      - 410
    type: Extbase
    extension: extension_name_here
    plugin: plugin_name_here
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{training-identifier}'
        _controller: 'Trainee::show'
        _arguments:
          training-identifier: training
    defaultController: 'Trainee::list'
    aspects:
      training-identifier:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: tx_extensioname_domain_model_training
        routeFieldPattern: '^(?<urlslug>.+)$'
        routeFieldResult: '{urlslug}'
```

--- edit 11:55 am --

I've just looked up *typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Routing/Aspect/PersistedPatternMapper.php* and there the queryBuilder never ask for the "hidden" field. So according to the RestrictionBuilder https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/RestrictionBuilder/Index.html it sets the hidden requirement. But you can overwrite it via TCA settings. Is there a way to edit this TCA setting for a pid or only for the action in the controller?

-- edit 12:09 am --

It works after I add this to the ext_tables.php. But then I can't use the *hidden* parameter of *trainings* at all.

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_extnNameHere_domain_model_training']['ctrl']['enablecolumns']['disabled'] = null;
```

Comment: you might consider to use a data field instead of a control field. if trainees 'disable' a course it is just a state for this course which is independent from the visibility of this record in TYPO3. even for the Frontend it only should be a filter. then you don't get a conflict with the 'enableFields' of TYPO3.

Comment: That is the better solution I guess. The only disadvantage you have with this is that you can't deactivate items in the TCA BE lists with the on off button. But for this circumstance I guess it's a fair solution. Thanks for the input @BerndWilkeπφ :)